# how connect owl carousel to wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, owl-carousel

I integrate owl carousel slider to wordpress theme.

In function.php i integrate scripts

```js
 wp_enqueue_script( 'navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/jquery/dist/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array(), 'jquery-3.4.1.min.js', true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.js', array(), 'OwlCarousel2-2.3.4', true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'all', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ), 'slider', true );
```

In console I have error TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function.

where I wrong?

Comment: There is a plugin for wordpress *already!*

Comment: First verify carousel.js load or not in footer then already jQuery library included in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

> For using Owl Carousel in WordPress. First you need to enqueue scripts
> and style of owl carousel and query in file name functions.php.

See more on: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html

Reference for wp_enqueue_style: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
and wp_enqueue_script: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
function loadup_scripts()
{
  wp_enqueue_style('owl-carousel-css','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css', array('jquery'),'2.3.4','all');
wp_enqueue_style('owl-theme-default-css','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css', array('jquery'),'2.3.4', 'all');

wp_enqueue_script('owl-carousel-js','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js',array('jquery','2.3.4',true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadup_scripts' );
```

#Call the plugin using Wp_footer action in footer

```
function livewellnutritionuk_action() { ?>
    <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){

         jQuery('.slider').slick({
          infinite: false,
          speed: 100,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 4,
          autoplay: true,
          prevArrow: '<span class="priv_arrow">&lt;</span>',
          nextArrow: '<span class="priv_arrow">&gt;</span>',
          responsive: [
                {
                  breakpoint: 1024,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 600,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  breakpoint: 480,
                  settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                  }
                }
             ]
            });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'livewellnutritionuk_action');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin [OWL CAROUSEL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slide-anything/)
thanks